# Audio Source Not Playing Unity3d?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to play an AudioSource when the trigger is entered by the player but for some reason nothing is working.

I have an Audio Source on the coin that the player will pick up and a sound attached to that audio source.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DingSoundPlay : MonoBehaviour {

public AudioSource DingAudioSource;

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        DingAudioSource.Play();
        Debug.Log ("Sound Played");
    }
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

It might be better for a Coin sound to use the PlayOneShot() method for this, this needs an AudioClip though:

```
public AudioClip audioClip

DingAudioSource.PlayOneShot(audioClip);
```